# Subscribing a callback function

Tags: angular, callback, rxjs, observable

I am developing an Angular application.

I have an AppController with the following post function:

```
public post(url: string, reqData: Object, options: RequestOptionsArgs,successHandler?:any): Observable<any> {
    let observable: Observable<any> = this.restClient.post(url, reqData, options)
    if(this.successCallback){
        observable.subscribe(this.successCallback);
    }
    return observable;
}
```

the function has an optional successHandler callback parameter. If it is available, the observable subscribes to it.

I have a service class having the following function which uses post function from AppController.

```
private postForm(reqdata: any): Observable<CustomerProfile> {

return this.appController.post(URL, reqdata,this.successCallback)
    .map((response) => {   
        let custProfile = new CustomerProfile();
        custProfile = response;
        return custProfile;
    }     
}
```

My problem is if the successHandler is available the `map()` operator in service is ignored and observable subscribes to the successHandler.

Is there a better approach for this problem, so that the `map()` operator gets executed even if I provide a callback.

Comment: Why is the service calling the controller? That seems like a really weird arrangement and puts your map and subscribe the wrong way around.

Comment: Can u recommend a better approach pls. Currently my architecture is something like Component->Service->AppController->RestClient

Comment: @Alexander Ideally `Component` and `AppComponent` will call functions of `service` and listen from `service`'s events. You can use `Subject` in `service` to work that out. More here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service